# Dynamic Table JQuery Editting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic-tables

I am totally newbie for JQuery but I need someone help for this part. 
I m dealing with a dynamic table from a template. I wish to remove the 10 records per page section but I have no idea how to do so. Anyone please?

Here is the HTML code which I still understandable

```
<table class="table table-striped border-top" id="sample_1">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <!-- <th style="width:8px;"><input type="checkbox" class="group-checkable" data-set="#sample_1 .checkboxes" /></th> -->
            <th>No</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th class="hidden-phone">Name</th>
            <th class="hidden-phone">Text</th>
            <th class="hidden-phone">Text</th>
            <th class="hidden-phone">Text</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <!-- <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1" /></td> -->
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Jhone doe</td>
            <td class="hidden-phone"><a href="mailto:jhone-doe@gmail.com">jhone-doe@gmail.com</a></td>
            <td class="hidden-phone">10</td>
            <td class="center hidden-phone">02.03.2013</td>
            <td class="hidden-phone"><span class="label label-success">Approved</span></td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="odd gradeX">
            <!-- <td><input type="checkbox" class="checkboxes" value="1" /></td> -->
            <td>2</td>
            <td>dipsdf</td>
            <td class="hidden-phone"><a href="mailto:soa bal@gmail.com">lorem-ip@gmail.com</a></td>
            <td class="hidden-phone">33</td>
            <td class="center hidden-phone">05.04.2013</td>
            <td class="hidden-phone"><span class="label label-success">Approved</span></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Jquery part which I have no idea what it doing there

```
var Script = function () {

    // begin first table
    $('#sample_1').dataTable({
        "sDom": "<'row'<'col-sm-6'l><'col-sm-6'f>r>t<'row'<'col-sm-6'i><'col-sm-6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sPrevious": "Prev",
                "sNext": "Next"
            }
        },
        "aoColumnDefs": [{
            'bSortable': false,
            'aTargets': [0]
        }]
    });

    jQuery('#sample_1 .group-checkable').change(function () {
        var set = jQuery(this).attr("data-set");
        var checked = jQuery(this).is(":checked");
        jQuery(set).each(function () {
            if (checked) {
                $(this).attr("checked", true);
            } else {
                $(this).attr("checked", false);
            }
        });
        jQuery.uniform.update(set);
    });

    jQuery('#sample_1_wrapper .dataTables_filter input').addClass("form-control"); // modify table search input
    jQuery('#sample_1_wrapper .dataTables_length select').addClass("form-control"); // modify table per page dropdown}();
```

I am trying to link the table with display data from database while replacing the 10 records per page section with an add button there. Anyone please.

Appreciate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to list all the records at once (plus hide the option to change number show per page) you have to disable pagination.

Add the following option to your datatables call.

```
"bPaginate": false
```

Read more about Datatable options [here](http://datatables.net/ref).

**EDIT**

If you still want to paginate but just hide the "per page" option, use the following option instead.

```
"bLengthChange": false
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vyE9N/2/)

Comment: Thanks for the info. Eventually it removed the bottom paginate as well =( Any idea how to remove the top 1 rather than removing both??

Comment: @CarsonLee I've updated my answer, check it out and let me know if it helps any.

Comment: Perfect Match bro =D But I would like to know how to add the button into it n fit nicely? Cause I can't really found CSS to put the button into nice place like the bLengthChange place.

Comment: @CarsonLee Sorry, I'm not sure I understand you correctly. You want a button where the dropdown list would be?